# Objective-C - Using Enum identifiers as string

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

The enumeration below is used in several places in a BMI tool :

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, BMIStatus) {
    Malnutrition = 1,
    Anorexia = 2,
    Thinness = 3,
    Normal = 4,
    Overweight = 5,
    Obesity = 6,
    Morbid = 7
};
```

Is there a trick to use "Malnutrition" as a string ? Considering I have an image named "Malnutrition.png" that I want to load with a classical ImageNamed, and without using an intermediary array storing `[1] => @"Malnutrition"` for example.

My idea would be to use a kind of `[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%e", Malnutrition]]` where %e leads to the enum identifier instead of the associated value.

Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly why people add prefixes to enum to prevent this problem. I'm not sure of a workaround for this, but I would recommend adding prefixes (such as your class prefixes) to your enum here.

Comment: I can't see how a prefix could allow me to find the string @"Malnutrition" with ease, even if i agree with the recommendation of prefixing the enum.

Comment: Sorry I totally misunderstood your problem. You could create a function, something like `NSString *BMIStatusToString(NSInteger n)` which converts each value to a certain NSString, would that be an alright solution?

Comment: Yes it is, as @colinbrash solution. A mapping methods seems to be the only viable solution here.

Comment: Why do you want to use enums? Global constants are the better choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is just not possible using Objective-C.  However, it is in Swift if you can use Swift instead.

This is historically handled in Apple's code with `NSString` constants.  For example:

```
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const NSFontAttributeName NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

If you need to map between the `int` value and the `NSString` value, you will need to write a mapping function.

Also, do make sure to prefix your enums and string constants!

Comment: Actually I already updated my enum names with prefixes :) Thank you for answer, that was the solution I expected. But I wanted to be sure there were no other solution before implementing it !

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string for debugging purposes, add a method `- (NSString*) stringFromBMIStatus`, with a switch statement returning various strings, and a default printing the numeric value for unexpected input.

If you want a string that gives you the name of an `NSImage` for each enum value, add a method `- (NSString*) imageNameFromBMIStatus`, probably returning nil for unexpected input.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I did. Nevertheless, i'm still wondering on where it would be optimal to declare those methods.